# How to make a method to presses a key?

Tags: java, class, methods, keyevent

so basically i am using the Robot class to make a method in which a key is pressed and released. But I don't know how to get it so that it uses a variable to determine what key to press.

here is what I have so far:

```
   void PressKey(String key)
{
    try {

            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.delay(200 + (int)(Math.random() * ((300 - 200) + 1)));
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);


        } catch (AWTException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with: `if some_condition: robot.keyPress(blah)`?

Comment: ... do you know how much code that would take? there are at least 80 different keys for it to press.

Answer (score 1):

Just abstract that out to some other method or a class that manages it:

```
robot.keyPress(getSomeKey());

public KeyEvent getSomeKey() {
    //use some internal logic to determine what to return
}
```

Comment: +1 for an extremely simple and maintainable solution

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [KeyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) states that `VK_0 thru VK_9 are the same as ASCII '0' thru '9'` and that `VK_A thru VK_Z are the same as ASCII 'A' thru 'Z' (0x41 - 0x5A)`. Therefore, if you are only looking to press alphanumeric keys, you can just pass the character that you want to be pressed to `keyPress`.

If you're looking for the function keys, you can instead pass the numeric value of that key to  `keyPress`. Note that the value of these keys may be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED).

Comment: This may very well be related to the internal logic that is a component of Rouge's response.